# heroku commands are hanging on windows CMD

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am new to heroku.I installed heroku toolbelt few days ago and was able to run commands like heroku version, heroku login and heroku create without any issue.Today I was trying to follow instructions in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-spring-mvc-hibernate and installed PostgreSQL in my machine.But I am not able to run any of the commands suddenly.Cursor just keeps blinking.Could any one please advise me how to fix this

Comment: something is stuck. Can you show me the output of `~/.heroku/error.log`

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Install and use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)

Solution 2:

1. Install [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) with Git Bash option.
2. Then use the Git Bash CLI to execute Heroku commands.